# sveltekit endpoint and mongodb post request 500 failure

Tags: mongodb, http-status-code-500, sveltekit

I am doing the usual todo app with sveltekit and MongoDB. I have an endpoint post request that just keeps failing with a 500 internal server failure. I can't seem to find much on google, and I am not familiar enough with sveltekit to know what it is.

I tried using a browser extension to allow CORS, but the error still occurred. I also tried removing the options from `$lib/db.ts`.

NADA, just 500 internal server failure.

1. $lib/db.ts

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env['MONGODB_URI'];
const options = {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!uri) {
    throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

if (process.env['NODE_ENV'] === 'development') {
    // In development mode, use a global variable
    // so that the value is preserved across module reloads
    // caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
    if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
        client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
        global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
    }
    clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
    // In production mode, it's best to
    // not use a global variable.
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise.
// By doing this in a separate module,
// the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

2. routes/todos/index.ts

```js
import clientPromise from '$lib/db';

export async function post(request) {
    try {
        const dbConnection = await clientPromise;
        const db = dbConnection.db();
        const collection = db.collection('sk-todo');
        const todo = JSON.parse(request.body);
        const newTodo = await collection.insertOne(todo);

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                newTodo
            }
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: {
                error: 'error during this post request'
            }
        };
    }
}
```

3. routes/index.svelte

```html
<script>
    let text = '';

    async function addTodo() {
        try {
            const todo = {
                text,
                completed: false
            };
            await fetch('/todos', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(todo)
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        if (text !== '') {
            console.log('todo added');
            text = '';
        }
    }
</script>

<h1 class="text-green-600">sveltekit todos</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={text} class="border" placeholder="enter todo" />
<button on:click={addTodo}>add todo</button>
```

Comment: What error messages are displayed in the console alongside the 500?

Comment: same problem here, cant find the solution. @kenset There are no error messages other than that

Comment: Can you put a console.log(error) in the catch block of `routes/todos/index.ts`